# 9 V to 12 V step-up converter to drive load between 10-100 mA, and no load

Tags: circuit-analysis, voltage-regulator, switching-regulator, buck-boost, step-up

I'm working on stepping up the voltage from a 9 V, 150 mA power supply to 12 V, with a load of 10-100 mA and moments where there's no load.

I have implemented something similar with this IC [ADP1612_1613](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADP1612_1613.pdf), but with 5 V. However, the efficiency decreases as the load decreases and it seems that as the load current increases, the power supply current increases, which will be driven almost to the limit of my 150 mA current supply. I'm already using some of that current to power other parts of my circuit, so I decided to not continue using this IC.

However, maybe I could use the 9 V from my power supply instead of my voltage regulator 5 V to only step up the voltage 3 more volts. For external reasons, I can not change my power adaptor to 12 V which is a fix. I'm having a hard time finding an IC that will deliver good efficiency at low loads and the 12 V I need, while keeping the number of components used at a minimum.

What would be a good way to just step up 9 V to 12 V while being able to deliver 10-100 mA?

Comment: Even with perfect efficiency (won't happen), to get 100 mA at 12 V from a 9 V supply means drawing almost 135 mA from the 9 V supply. Don't you agree? How much of the 150 mA do you need for your 5 V supply? I don't think you will have anything left over for it.

Comment: Numbers are needed. Good efficiency at low loads means "what" at "which" load current (for example)? Maximum number of components means what?

Comment: @jonk yes I agree efficiency won't be perfect, but I was trying to have at least an 80% efficiency.I have done some basic mesurmaents,  now I'm using two TLC277 op amps ICs, a pic18f micro, and a buzzer with pwm, now the buzzer is design with an inductor to draw more current to create a loud sound at its max the buzzer draws 90-100ma, and at it lowest 30ma and of coruse not continuously (pwm).

Comment: Therefore, the overall system draws about  110-140ma with the buzzer low or high, and only about 50-60ma when the buzzer is off. I think with a limited power supply current, boosting the voltage will not be ideal at all, and will put my power supply at its limit or not over even if enable the buzzer to draw only 30-40ma. The switching current on a convertor will be too much for my power supply to handle. I think the best and optimal solution would have to be to just change the power supply to 12V and with more than 150ma if possible, but is hard to find a 3-pin type B power supply with gound.

Comment: @Citi Optimal is a matter of opinion. But figure out the total power you require and the cheapest way to get it. Sometimes, you can find a nice device that provides a variety of voltages. I would not be surprised if you could find a nice switcher providing both 5 V and 12 V rails (most all PCs have those two, for example.) So, if you don't actually *need* 9 V, then look for something that already provides the two voltages you really do need (at the currents you need.) And then don't worry. Otherwise, yeah. Pick a 12 V supply with enough current and just use a linear or buck to get 5 V.

Answer (score 1):

Making calculations:

[image]

Maybe you could use the [LMR62014](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lmr62014.pdf?ts=1664106541622&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F). If you use the [texas power designer tool](https://webench.ti.com/power-designer/switching-regulator?powerSupply=0) with all of these parameters you talk about you get this circuit with 92% of efficiency.
[image]

I hope this helps :D !

Comment: this is great but I realize that the best and optimal solution would be to increase my power supply voltage/current to 12V and at least 150ma or 9V with at least 500ma-1A. Texas power designer tool seems like a great tool thank you for sharing